# How to open a new terminal by commands in a shell scripts?

Tags: shell, terminal, command, ubuntu-12.04

I have two set of commands to be executed from different directories from a shell script.

My content of the shell script is below:

```
echo "starting Windshaft cartodb..."
cd /home/user/Windshaft-cartodb/
node app.js development
echo "Windshaft cartodb started."

echo "starting CartoDB SQL API..."
cd /home/user/CartoDB-SQL-API/
node app.js development
echo "CartoDB SQL API started."
```

When I run the shell script file, the first 3 commands were running successfully. In order to run the next commands, I have to stop the previously running command by pressing Ctrl + C. Script processing continues with `echo "Windshaft cartodb started."` only after doing this.

My problem is: Without stopping the previously running commands, I need to execute the commands after the below commands in a new terminal.

```
echo "starting Windshaft cartodb..."
cd /home/user/Windshaft-cartodb/
node app.js development
```

How to open a new terminal by commands in a shell script?

Comment: You can run the first `node app.js development` in background with `&` at the end of command. so `node app.js development &`

Comment: If i use & it goes to the next command, but it raising an error after executing   next set of commands  [2015-12-16 06:49:12.890] [ERROR] [default] - Uncaught exception: Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1042:14)
    at listen (net.js:1064:10)
    at net.js:1146:9
    at dns.js:72:18
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3

Answer (score 0):

> How to open a new terminal by commands in a shell script?

You can open a new terminal with the command `xterm` and run a program in it with its option `-e`:

```
xterm -e node app.js development&
```